# AttributeError in Python Tornado to configure log into a file

Tags: python-2.7, logging, tornado, attributeerror, setattribute

when I try to configure my Python Tornado Web Server to log into a file, I always get an **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'** exception.

Below the code I'm using to do this:

`tornado.options.options["log_file_prefix"].set("local.log")`

I tried to go through documentation and some example from internet, but I didn't find anything.

I'm using **tornado 4.2.1** with **Python 2.7.9**.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attribute assignment syntax:

```
tornado.options.options.log_file_prefix = "local.log"
```

Comment: Thank you Ben Darnell for your replay!

I tried that, but I got this error:
**TypeError: 'OptionParser' object does not support item assignment**

Comment: Oops, looks like assignment doesn't work with square bracket syntax; only with attribute syntax. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, it works! Really thank you Ben Darnell for your time!